# Do there exist two distinct such points?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Please tell me if my attempt on the following problem will work:

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic in $|z|≤r.$ Do there exist two distinct points $z_0 = re^{iθ_0}$ and $z_1 = re^{iθ_1}$ such that $|f(z)|≤|f(z_0)|$ and $|f(z)|≤|f(z_1)|$ 
>   for all $z, |z| <r?$

My Attempt: **Not necessarily true.**

Justification: Let $f(z)=e^z.$ Then $|f(z)|=e^{\Re z}~\forall~z\in\mathbb C...(1)$

Now by maximum modulus principle $f$ (being analytic on $|z|\le r$) attains it maximum on $|z|=r.$ Due to $(1),~f$ has it maximum at $z=r.$

Choose $z_0(\ne r)$ such that $|z_0|=r.$ It suffices to show that $\exists~z'$ such that $|z_1|<r$ even though $|f(z_1)|>|f(z_0)|.$

$z_0\ne r \implies |\Re (z_0)|<r\implies|f(z_0)|<r.$

Choose $r_1\in\mathbb R$ such that $|f(z_0)|<e^{r_1}<e^r.$ Then choosing $z'=r$ serves the purpose.

Comment: Looks good to me. Since the disk is inside $-r \leq Re z \leq r$ you don't even need the Maximum Modulus Principle.

Comment: The idea is right and works, in the write-up, you made a few msitakes. 0. You wrote "attends" instead of "attains". 1. In the last line, you should have $\lvert f(z_0)\rvert < e^{r_1} < e^{r}$, and "Then choosing $z' = r_1$".